# How to share score on Facebook using Swift 2.0 and Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

This code runs without any problem, but in the GameOver scene it doesn't show the share to Facebook button. Help would be appreciated.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import Social
import UIKit
import GameKit
import iAd
import AudioToolbox

class GameOver: SKScene {

let won:Bool

init(size: CGSize, won: Bool) {
    self.won = won
    super.init(size: size)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

@IBOutlet weak var shareImg: UIImageView!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    var background: SKSpriteNode
    if (won) {
        background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "YouWin")
        runAction(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1),
            SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("win.wav",
                waitForCompletion: false)
            ]))
    } else {
        background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background1")

        var youLose: SKLabelNode!

        youLose = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
        youLose.text = "Merry Christmas!"
        youLose.fontSize = 100
        youLose.fontColor = SKColor.redColor()
        youLose.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Left
        youLose.position = CGPoint(x: 550, y: 950)
        youLose.zPosition = 1
        addChild(youLose)

        scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvatica")
        scoreLabel.text = "You have \(score) Presents collected!"
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 60
        scoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor.redColor()
        scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Right
        scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 1400, y: 750)
        scoreLabel.zPosition = 100
        addChild(scoreLabel)

        runAction(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.waitForDuration(0.2),
            SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("lose.mp3",
                waitForCompletion: false)
            ]))


    }

    background.position =
        CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    self.addChild(background)

    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(7.0)
    let block = SKAction.runBlock {
        let myScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
        myScene.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
        let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
        self.view?.presentScene(myScene, transition: reveal)
        score = 0
    }
    self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([wait, block]))

}


// FACEBOOK BUTTON
@IBAction func facebookButt(sender: AnyObject) {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let viewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController

    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
        let fb = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        fb.setInitialText("I have collected \(score) presents!")
        fb.addImage(shareImg.image)
        viewController!.presentViewController(fb, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Facebook",
            message: "Please login to your Facebook account in Settings",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        viewController!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Where are you adding the button? I can only see an action for it.

Comment: I want to add it at the end of func didMoveToView()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Facebook button can only be added to a `UIView`, you'll need to add it to the `SKView` that looks after your `GameOver` scene .

In your didMoveToView() function you can do something like this:

```
let facebookButton = // setup button here. Set frame etc.
view.addSubview(facebookButton)
```

Each SKScene has a reference to the view its contained in.

To call your action you created:

```
facebookButton.addTarget(self, action: "facebookButt:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: Thank you Beau, maybe this will create a button, how do I link this button to call @IBAction func facebookButt(sender: AnyObject), or instead of (sender: AnyObject) assign it to new uibutton?

Comment: see my edit above. should be all you need. And if your action isn't linked to the storyboard you can probably get rid of the preceding "@IBAction" text

Comment: This is what I have done, do I need to do anything in the AppDelegate?

Comment: let image = UIImage(named: "share") as UIImage?
            
                    let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
                    button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 30, 30, 20)
                    button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                    button.addTarget(self, action: "facebookButt:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
                    self.view?.addSubview(button)

Comment: What I have posted should work. If its not working you issues must be elsewhere, tell me whats not working, and what you have tried. I have answered the original question.

Comment: This is my first swift app, I have create the button and linked it to the facebookButt function, I could see a small button created, when I press it, i got Error in the AppDelegate

Comment: What error?!? Whatever it is, its now unrelated to the original question. Choose an answer, or delete this question, and ask another posting your app delegate code.

Comment: in AppDelegate: i have class AppDelegte: UIResponder, UIApplicateionDelegate {var window: UIWindow?}

Comment: That doesn't help me at all. Signals can be caused by almost anything. Like I said, your new error is unrelated to this question. Ask a new question, and either mark this one as solved or delete it.

Comment: I didn't have that error before, just appeared as I created the button!